# Why do bittorrent clients connect to seeds when they are themselves seeding

Tags: connection, bittorrent

I noticed that **when I'm seeding a torrent** (using Transmission, the default client under Ubuntu), **it regularly connects to other seeds**, to which, obviously, I won't send any data.

People I know have reported that they see the same behaviour using other torrent clients.

[image: Screenshot of Transmission's torrent property window with 3 connections to seeds and one to a peer]

These connections appear during a few seconds, and then vanish. Most of the time they are incoming connections, but I think I saw some outgoing ones once or twice.

Why are these seed-to-seed connections made? The only reason that makes sense to me is that they are used to maintain the DHT.

Comment: Apparently [uTorrent does not do this](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?pid=585550#p585550).

Answer (score -1):

Generally it's to check the integrity of your files, as to make sure that they aren't loaded with a virus or something like that. Notice how when you boot up, it says 'Checking files' or something like that(I use Tixati, so it's probably something else.)? It's because of that, as well as to see if you have the entire thing downloaded.

Comment: The torrent file contains the hash, there's no need to connect to other seeds to verify your downloaded files/pieces.